# Is there a way to try and load a file in HTML/JavaScript and have a fallback if it doesn't load?

Tags: javascript, html

I just switched to start using a CDN for external images/static files for my site and I wanted to know how I could build a backup in case this CDN failed.  Is there a way to reference an external link in an HTML/JavaScript file that would let you specify a fallback location for that file if it is unavailable in the first external host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first answer may not work in all browsers. You could just have some/remote/script.js set some variable "loaded=true" and then check it in the next script block.

```
<script>
loaded=false
</script>
<script src="some/remote/script.js"></script>
<script>
if(loaded==false){
  //do what you want here if it didn't load
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article on this here:  http://happyworm.com/blog/2010/01/28/a-simple-and-robust-cdn-failover-for-jquery-14-in-one-line/

This came in handy for me on a site using the Microsoft Ajax CDN to get jquery.  We had a few customers whose machines did not trust the SSL certificate from the CDN when we used jquery on HTTPS pages.    A local fallback is a good way to fix that problem.

We determined whether or not to inject the fallback by checking a variable the the script would have otherwise added to the global namespace.  e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript' %3E%3C/script%3E"));}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Great resource, but... can you make the answer stand without needing to follow the link?

Answer (score 0):

(**Edited: First attempt was wrong**)

```
<script src="some/remote/script.js">
    // Set a flag in the above script
</script>
<script>
    if ( ! flag ) {
        // This code runs if script.js fails to load for some reason
    }
</script>

<object data="http://cdn/file.png" type="image/png">
    <!-- You can nest objects in here too -->
    <img src="http://local/file.png" alt="Fallback Image"/>
</object>
```

So I suppose you could use the script method for everything; in the event the remote files fail to load, use the fallback code to change all paths to point to your backup server.

Comment: The script answer is wrong! (simple test under FF) - also see under http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-src-SCRIPT it tells you that "If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents"